# How to create a calculated field and use it in a list definition?

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

<Field
ID="{A57D77CA-9D80-458A-AB81-884C4F5A946D}"
Name="internalName"
StaticName="internalName"
DisplayName="Body"
Type="Text"
RichText="TRUE"
RichTextMode="FullHtml"
Required="FALSE"
Group="myGroup" />

<Field
ID="{BE6CFDC4-07CF-4175-99E7-E82259A41B5F}"
Name="internalName2"
StaticName="internalName2"
DisplayName="myBadField"
Type="Calculated"
RichText="TRUE"
RichTextMode="FullHtml"
Required="FALSE"
Group="myGroup">
<Formula>=[Body]</Formula>
</Field>

</Elements>
```

I created a content type based on those fields and then a list definition and a list instance. I deployed it successfully. But when I am creating a new entry in my list I got the following message:

> Cannot complete this action. Please try again.
>
> COMException (0x80004005)

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Two things here:

1. Use Internal Name of the field in Formula
2. Add FieldRefs to calculated field.
3. Remove `RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml"`
4. Add `ResultType=""`

Your field definition should look like this:

```
<Field
    ID="{BE6CFDC4-07CF-4175-99E7-E82259A41B5F}"
    Name="internalName2"
    StaticName="internalName2"
    DisplayName="myBadField"
    Type="Calculated"
    Required="FALSE"
    ResultType="Text"
    Group="myGroup">
    <Formula>=(internalName)</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="internalName" ID="{A57D77CA-9D80-458A-AB81-884C4F5A946D}" />
    </FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

Note: there might be square brackets [] instead of () in the Formula. Or there might be no brackets at all depending on the formula. Here is a working example:

```
<Formula>=(IF(AND(Score&gt;0,Score&lt;5),"Green",IF(AND(Score&gt;4,Score&lt;10),"Amber",IF(Score&gt;9,"Red",""))))</Formula>
```

Add multiple FieldRefs for the same field as well if you are using them in the formula multiple times. If, for example, internalName field was a number, and you wanted to check if the value falls between two numbers:

```
<Field
    ID="{BE6CFDC4-07CF-4175-99E7-E82259A41B5F}"
    Name="internalName2"
    StaticName="internalName2"
    DisplayName="myBadField"
    Type="Calculated"
    Required="FALSE"
    ResultType="Text"
    Group="myGroup">
    <Formula>=(IF(AND(internalName&gt;0,internalName&lt;5),"Good","No good")</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="internalName" ID="{A57D77CA-9D80-458A-AB81-884C4F5A946D}" />
          <FieldRef Name="internalName" ID="{A57D77CA-9D80-458A-AB81-884C4F5A946D}" />
    </FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

I usually add the following XML properties to my Calculated fields:

```
Format=""
ResultType=""
```

(don't forget to assign values to those properties as well :) E.g.:

```
Format="DateOnly"
ResultType="Text"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunetly It did not work. I noticed that the "myBadField" field does not showing up when I'm trying to add a list item. But may be it's normal.

Comment: Did you add the same field definition to list schema as well? By the way, remove RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" from your calculated field.

Comment: I did not modified the list schema.xml file. Why do I have to do it ? I thought It was generated automatically ? And according to what I see, it did.

Comment: Because there are 3 steps you need to follow: 1. Define the field as a site column. 2. Reference the field in a content type 3. Add your field to list schema definition so that the list can use the field. Follow this guide for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728096.aspx The only case where you don't define Fields in list schema is if you don't use them in any formulas or do any customization to them, otherwise they must be in the list schema.

Comment: As I said the schema.xml was update when I modified the Fields, Content Type and List Definition. Probably because I'm using Visual Studio to do it by checking some checkbox buttons. Whatever. The important thing is that the fields are already there and well formed. Moreover, the other fields are workings perfectly. Even if I did modified them as well.

Comment: Paste an updated field definition here please.